# URL returns 504 error when called from HTTP

Tags: java, http, asynchronous, jersey

I have this code, to trigger some async http calls:

```
private CompleteRoutingResponseWrapper sendRoutingRequestString(int numOfTries, String routingRequestUrl) {
    routingRequestUrl = urlUtils.getHttpUrl(routingRequestUrl);

    CompleteRoutingResponseWrapper answer = new CompleteRoutingResponseWrapper();
    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    CloseableHttpResponse response = null;
    try {

        Stopwatch stopWatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();
        response = client.execute(new HttpGet(routingRequestUrl));
        stopWatch.stop();

        int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode != 200) {
            answer = retryOrHandleError(numOfTries, routingRequestUrl, answer, response, statusCode);
        } else {
            String bodyAsString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            answer.completeRoutingResponse = handleSuccess(bodyAsString);
            answer.latency = stopWatch.elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            handleErrorInBody(routingRequestUrl, answer, bodyAsString);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    handleNullResponse(answer);
    return answer;
}
```

and

```
    @Override
    public E2EResult sendBaselineRoutingRequestsInParallel(E2EResult e2EResult, List<String> routingRequestsList) {
        List<Callable<Void>> callables = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < routingRequestsList.size(); i++) {
            final int position = i;
            callables.add(() -> {

//calls sendRoutingRequestString()

                synchronized (e2EResult) {
                    e2EResult.addResponse(relativePosition, requestPosition, routingResponse);
                }
                return null;
            });
        }
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        try {
            executorService.invokeAll(callables);
            executorService.shutdown();
            executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return e2EResult;
    }
```

When the code calls this url
it always return 504.

```
http://myhost.com/routingRequest?returnJSON=true&timeout=60000&to=s%3A-1+d%3Afalse+f%3A-1.0+x%3A-71.25576+y%3A42.393196+r%3A-1.0+cd%3A-1.0+fn%3A-1+tn%3A-1+bd%3Atrue&nPaths=1&returnClientIds=true&hour=12+00&from=s%3A-1+d%3Afalse+f%3A-1.0+x%3A-71.270565+y%3A42.361661+r%3A-1.0+cd%3A-1.0+fn%3A18399181+tn%3A18418746+bd%3Afalse&sameResultType=true&type=HISTORIC_TIME&clientVersion=3.9.4.5&options=AVOID_PRIMARIES%3Afalse%2CIGNORE_REALTIME_INFO%3Afalse%2CAVOID_LONG_TRAILS%3Afalse%2CPREFER_SAME_STREET%3Atrue%2CAVOID_TRAILS%3Atrue%2CAVOID_TOLL_ROADS%3Afalse%2CALLOW_UTURNS%3Atrue%2CAVOID_DANGER_ZONES%3Afalse%2CUSE_EXTENDED_INSTRUCTIONS%3Atrue%2CALLOW_UNKNOWN_DIRECTIONS%3Atrue%2CPREFER_UNKNOWN_DIRECTIONS%3Afalse
2015-04-20 12:00:27,580 [pool-6-thread-37] INFO  linqmap.routing.server.RoutingServer - ROUTING RECORDED: http://104.155.3.206:8080/RoutingManager/routingRequest?returnJSON=true&timeout=60000&to=s%3A34790759+d%3Afalse+f%3A-1.0+x%3A-73.993644+y%3A40.725395+r%3A-1.0+cd%3A-1.0+fn%3A-1+tn%3A-1+bd%3Atrue+st%3ABleecker%7ESt&via=s%3A-1+d%3Afalse+f%3A-1.0+x%3A-73.970138+y%3A40.850933+r%3A-1.0+cd%3A-1.0+fn%3A-1+tn%3A-1+bd%3Atrue&nPaths=1&returnClientIds=true&hour=12+00&from=s%3A-1+d%3Afalse+f%3A-1.0+x%3A-74.499669+y%3A40.907095+r%3A-1.0+cd%3A-1.0+fn%3A26380096+tn%3A26369788+bd%3Afalse&sameResultType=true&type=HISTORIC_TIME&clientVersion=3.9.4.0&stickToPath=68748394%2C26380096%2C-74.499669%2C40.90709599999985%2C70124838%2C26369788%2C-74.4879635129%2C40.89700597919985%2C32022797%2C26363639%2C-74.47420799999999%2C40.888397%2C70124821%2C26364659%2C-74.473163%2C40.887729%2C70124763%2C26372113%2C-74.447036%2C40.867209%2C82165445%2C26383674%2C-74.436374%2C40.865995999999996%2C82165444%2C61632550%2C-74.42966579042002%2C40.86547995136578%2C32042389%2C26380593%2C-74.42253199999999%2C40.86481%2C32042368%2C26375759%2C-74.417202953606%2C40.864137081396%2C77279241%2C26375309%2C-74.41294095733805%2C40.863467589631426%2C70095591%2C26384446%2C-74.376045753363%2C40.859071166122%2C70095592%2C55924040%2C-74.37594651163%2C40.859023493747%2C32017573%2C26369682%2C-74.370465%2C40.858565999999996%2C32026992%2C26381802%2C-74.36630671163941%2C40.85963780064551%2C70103895%2C26355007%2C-74.364014%2C40.860688%2C32021149%2C26387421%2C-74.348252%2C40.862038%2C81799536%2C26366817%2C-74.332561746032%2C40.865046796007%2C81799535%2C61394559%2C-74.33080526129919%2C40.867546977540954%2C81594035%2C26462012%2C-74.267987%2C40.894009999999845%2C81594036%2C61275184%2C-74.26644658817527%2C40.894150992075915%2C31826149%2C26209096%2C-74.260271869698%2C40.895000358355%2C31836443%2C26211925%2C-74.243818%2C40.898628999999985%2C62831293%2C50477837%2C-74.236227%2C40.89951499999999%2C31828680%2C26216038%2C-74.223238%2C40.896674%2C66963280%2C26213495%2C-74.217292%2C40.896881%2C66963281%2C54921707%2C-74.201265640258%2C40.896215021313%2C62635498%2C26205873%2C-74.195631802082%2C40.902313879819%2C62634850%2C26205899%2C-74.193551%2C40.903933%2C31827500%2C53429193%2C-74.187740500651%2C40.906083895573%2C31828511%2C26207333%2C-74.175887620314%2C40.908608789887%2C62830630%2C26215611%2C-74.172994%2C40.908136999999996%2C31822835%2C26208588%2C-74.16542299999999%2C40.906765%2C31821799%2C26208587%2C-74.164087176322%2C40.906531725309%2C31827601%2C26203370%2C-74.150353%2C40.901033999999996%2C31822325%2C26210942%2C-74.148544%2C40.900763999999995%2C62828098%2C26216008%2C-74.141492947934%2C40.900902674596%2C62828099%2C26204554%2C-74.1343779705695%2C40.90196699999999%2C31780255%2C26162340%2C-74.133401%2C40.901947%2C31774342%2C26180321%2C-74.132723957298%2C40.901879908805%2C57800509%2C50482578%2C-74.130132943389%2C40.901439983379%2C57800530%2C50482627%2C-74.12250004970679%2C40.9021896397596%2C57798264%2C50476814%2C-74.109068017531%2C40.903956841396%2C57800593%2C50482750%2C-74.101260107091%2C40.903513888913%2C77686519%2C50482775%2C-74.0948363245252%2C40.90314988083412%2C77686520%2C59180515%2C-74.0947520105031%2C40.90312009790261%2C57800610%2C50482827%2C-74.084037681225%2C40.900899572758%2C57800659%2C50482862%2C-74.079242%2C40.894788%2C57800667%2C50482884%2C-74.073051353099%2C40.889947032595%2C57628284%2C50204031%2C-74.070806%2C40.88786499999999%2C80919510%2C50483627%2C-74.065405%2C40.880548000000005%2C80919511%2C60920945%2C-74.06535647780983%2C40.88044267815794%2C57781450%2C50443308%2C-74.061952372194%2C40.874603940104%2C57801359%2C50483695%2C-74.05936865639366%2C40.871635692932124%2C57801387%2C50483771%2C-74.056716700197%2C40.86936505963%2C57801383%2C50483766%2C-74.053224464059%2C40.867730233131%2C57801441%2C50483931%2C-74.0458106541614%2C40.866854252450985%2C57801438%2C50483925%2C-74.03857089857533%2C40.866849932787666%2C57801489%2C50484048%2C-74.03333388547412%2C40.866929039277%2C70111230%2C50204034%2C-74.015414%2C40.864736%2C70111231%2C55929102%2C-74.01534574758949%2C40.864744383293896%2C57801554%2C50484211%2C-74.010145%2C40.864293999999994%2C57801555%2C50484214%2C-74.0057239933%2C40.866047894927%2C31775344%2C50475854%2C-74.003973640142%2C40.867462615956%2C77904107%2C55775406%2C-74.00046072799489%2C40.867327034479956%2C67535147%2C26183541%2C-73.99894732645%2C40.866741567445%2C62813313%2C50534492%2C-73.99537791863%2C40.865405376558%2C77248723%2C26177925%2C-73.9939651232032%2C40.86486225037791%2C31799901%2C26185233%2C-73.992961%2C40.864447999999996%2C31798621%2C26174851%2C-73.99230399999999%2C40.864193%2C31795568%2C26164610%2C-73.991546%2C40.86383%2C31803414%2C26164611%2C-73.99046899999999%2C40.863208%2C31818540%2C26178529%2C-73.99041%2C40.863174%2C67201279%2C26177935%2C-73.989553%2C40.862674%2C67201280%2C54995870%2C-73.989412352115%2C40.862591913944%2C76256218%2C26177934%2C-73.98871%2C40.862182%2C75329485%2C26178537%2C-73.987951%2C40.861739%2C75329486%2C58130509%2C-73.98712145379588%2C40.861250469190374%2C75329474%2C58130505%2C-73.9869842878087%2C40.861169689966246%2C31799910%2C26178554%2C-73.98665199999999%2C40.860974%2C31812452%2C26178555%2C-73.985675%2C40.860397999999996%2C31812451%2C26185240%2C-73.98501999999999%2C40.860071%2C31790726%2C26195967%2C-73.98475700000002%2C40.860006999999996%2C31779452%2C26193617%2C-73.98389399999999%2C40.859863%2C31790723%2C26190049%2C-73.983762%2C40.859840999999996%2C31805237%2C26190051%2C-73.982719%2C40.859637%2C31819138%2C26169419%2C-73.981672%2C40.859044999999995%2C31773857%2C26169420%2C-73.981427%2C40.85881%2C62036986%2C26178548%2C-73.981338%2C40.858725%2C31816656%2C26161652%2C-73.980741146427%2C40.858183753144%2C31816657%2C26165984%2C-73.980238%2C40.85776900000001%2C31810422%2C26165692%2C-73.97998879147944%2C40.857540991908515%2C74600609%2C26165691%2C-73.979383%2C40.856932%2C31815682%2C26175755%2C-73.97734928131%2C40.855339304184%2C31792625%2C26174853%2C-73.976708233356%2C40.854905155558%2C31798884%2C26175766%2C-73.97572199999999%2C40.85427%2C66631511%2C26192606%2C-73.975037%2C40.85383099999999%2C66631510%2C54813651%2C-73.974560011985%2C40.85352644857%2C74600608%2C59100141%2C-73.97417578509189%2C40.85327482413075%2C63804663%2C26176022%2C-73.97232799999999%2C40.852081999999996%2C63804661%2C53781615%2C-73.971738345429%2C40.85169545142%2C31816684%2C26176021%2C-73.971051%2C40.851321%2C77739023%2C26183375%2C-73.970163%2C40.851185%2C77739023%2C26183375%2C-73.970163%2C40.851185%2C77739023%2C26183375%2C-73.970163%2C40.851185%2C76625064%2C58641827%2C-73.97047306871995%2C40.85063137012922%2C63640510%2C53727805%2C-73.970500402135%2C40.850200511658%2C31801169%2C26166007%2C-73.970465533418%2C40.850005738641%2C77226611%2C58940642%2C-73.97035448674053%2C40.84953254404849%2C77226602%2C58940637%2C-73.9704901172258%2C40.84877280674154%2C82857216%2C52894951%2C-73.97069092503267%2C40.848207731172614%2C82857217%2C62025109%2C-73.97098939772309%2C40.84700235053454%2C83096982%2C26165719%2C-73.97102458649302%2C40.8467898564558%2C62038167%2C26165720%2C-73.97114096197254%2C40.846033948618086%2C31802739%2C26176026%2C-73.9715421199809%2C40.845449397422975%2C31800810%2C26163597%2C-73.9720159362858%2C40.84486800580796%2C31795303%2C26163596%2C-73.9724531363555%2C40.844258274716566%2C31791991%2C26176028%2C-73.97282462230335%2C40.84361911630188%2C31802725%2C26182044%2C-73.9731840383119%2C40.84297792261919%2C31789177%2C26163600%2C-73.97364135494907%2C40.842367159577286%2C77280806%2C26163599%2C-73.97417645564737%2C40.84181827968296%2C77280807%2C58968557%2C-73.97479202261584%2C40.84127142439922%2C31798976%2C26166022%2C-73.97516350856507%2C40.84093356906518%2C31798969%2C26166021%2C-73.976036%2C40.840157000000005%2C31802741%2C26183382%2C-73.976615%2C40.839631%2C31802742%2C26166017%2C-73.976975%2C40.839303%2C31792750%2C26166016%2C-73.97720199999999%2C40.839096999999995%2C31780868%2C26176031%2C-73.97774700000001%2C40.838542%2C62832556%2C26195419%2C-73.978069999999%2C40.838165648992%2C31789400%2C26195101%2C-73.978252112865%2C40.8374718459%2C31798977%2C26183388%2C-73.978287%2C40.836658%2C31801174%2C26176044%2C-73.978375%2C40.835117%2C31778949%2C26176048%2C-73.978509%2C40.832657%2C31802743%2C26192705%2C-73.978662%2C40.832332%2C31816709%2C26166026%2C-73.97895199999999%2C40.831683%2C31778945%2C26166025%2C-73.979187%2C40.831100000000006%2C31782808%2C26176010%2C-73.979233%2C40.830985999999996%2C31802137%2C26181385%2C-73.97925599999999%2C40.83093%2C31795997%2C26162446%2C-73.97951800000001%2C40.830373%2C31771610%2C26166695%2C-73.979886%2C40.829705%2C68977567%2C26166692%2C-73.979946%2C40.82959699999999%2C31810388%2C26175714%2C-73.980231%2C40.82904400000001%2C31810387%2C26165657%2C-73.98055989204899%2C40.82842328993616%2C31810386%2C26165656%2C-73.980919%2C40.827777999999995%2C31795306%2C26175706%2C-73.9813065277863%2C40.82713770144806%2C31816396%2C26174077%2C-73.98170751803282%2C40.82648011147272%2C31816398%2C26165655%2C-73.98211189203076%2C40.82583334073236%2C31801105%2C26165654%2C-73.98272048098565%2C40.82532226680017%2C31792604%2C26165662%2C-73.98355184540367%2C40.82491817794042%2C31778903%2C26175708%2C-73.98414841104508%2C40.82447213351656%2C31792605%2C26183180%2C-73.9841981009446%2C40.82441408209391%2C31810385%2C26183179%2C-73.984342940231%2C40.824231411363%2C31795861%2C26175713%2C-73.984683580776%2C40.823836637902%2C31792607%2C26165664%2C-73.984981305977%2C40.823486515512%2C31789684%2C26165663%2C-73.985169060608%2C40.82324802529%2C31806752%2C26195337%2C-73.985387660642%2C40.823008519353%2C31784634%2C26188679%2C-73.98561028399%2C40.822646214237%2C31806762%2C26183186%2C-73.985698%2C40.8225134459592%2C67620351%2C26175716%2C-73.98643303571059%2C40.82202173965591%2C67620350%2C55128309%2C-73.98677286505641%2C40.822022742579406%2C62706668%2C53449529%2C-73.987300075668%2C40.821883337319%2C31787437%2C26165647%2C-73.9878712478504%2C40.821425699457855%2C31806757%2C26183178%2C-73.98805665969788%2C40.819965136381875%2C31815624%2C26182522%2C-73.988573%2C40.818338%2C31804675%2C26182521%2C-73.98876%2C40.817889%2C31804677%2C26188681%2C-73.988856%2C40.817597%2C31801106%2C26188682%2C-73.989188%2C40.816053%2C31810399%2C26192591%2C-73.98952114582%2C40.815308593098%2C31773361%2C26175723%2C-73.989818602802%2C40.814660762294%2C31816432%2C26175722%2C-73.98993393779%2C40.814407015504%2C68057831%2C26188690%2C-73.990028083324%2C40.814186020908%2C63645591%2C26165677%2C-73.99033921957%2C40.813024859346%2C31810416%2C26183211%2C-73.990562%2C40.811828999999996%2C62147815%2C26192603%2C-73.991249859651%2C40.809463832911%2C62147814%2C53283970%2C-73.992199445331%2C40.807327250841%2C31774768%2C26162949%2C-73.992184%2C40.807207%2C65095855%2C53214018%2C-73.992135494947%2C40.807083176004%2C65095861%2C54316573%2C-73.99175533652%2C40.806147863741%2C61247164%2C52739752%2C-73.993044137953%2C40.804476962681%2C31784707%2C26194897%2C-73.993277%2C40.8042%2C78083394%2C26166216%2C-73.993693%2C40.802893%2C77738922%2C26329685%2C-73.993993848562%2C40.800629702128%2C31983566%2C26329684%2C-73.995785564184%2C40.797628703534%2C75300322%2C26330597%2C-73.99686593225445%2C40.79561999690159%2C75300345%2C58120528%2C-73.9971623718514%2C40.79463880108679%2C75300344%2C58120536%2C-73.99756464362603%2C40.79342523478009%2C75300257%2C26329188%2C-73.998843282461%2C40.791252654063%2C67607832%2C55123681%2C-73.99915539615628%2C40.79072716678898%2C61223421%2C26329187%2C-73.99984204166375%2C40.78952091849904%2C70449012%2C52718613%2C-74.00017751496715%2C40.789078387394106%2C57798993%2C50479486%2C-74.00050186508145%2C40.78859794099461%2C71136093%2C50479472%2C-74.00073655837046%2C40.78827910970066%2C61965483%2C52739398%2C-74.00303674977678%2C40.785648356985405%2C31981218%2C53213525%2C-74.00416059535453%2C40.78454762288227%2C61965224%2C52739402%2C-74.005713%2C40.78371982520375%2C61965471%2C53213361%2C-74.006961%2C40.78322299999999%2C65091141%2C53213510%2C-74.008176807671%2C40.782660758767%2C65091140%2C54314892%2C-74.00930333545806%2C40.78141069773531%2C61246903%2C52739415%2C-74.0097861330802%2C40.78078515064632%2C78650194%2C52739418%2C-74.01037219574967%2C40.78002148777136%2C68002347%2C55252373%2C-74.010981495402%2C40.779170319091%2C65091643%2C52739433%2C-74.01189434936609%2C40.77810721445247%2C77264368%2C54315026%2C-74.01217909384205%2C40.77666271719232%2C77264370%2C58960364%2C-74.01208487877524%2C40.77599371191459%2C65091645%2C54315027%2C-74.012574289352%2C40.775124494048%2C63530968%2C53695704%2C-74.013888571769%2C40.773241563799%2C78650240%2C53446899%2C-74.01463710399635%2C40.77198542299794%2C76888728%2C58772673%2C-74.0153130206686%2C40.77066609636355%2C65969583%2C54602784%2C-74.0161766919711%2C40.76943409179636%2C76888794%2C58772707%2C-74.01797645421976%2C40.767705387355704%2C71224495%2C54602789%2C-74.01836289460584%2C40.76725164577135%2C71224497%2C56303590%2C-74.019101242437%2C40.76626582392%2C73123460%2C56303591%2C-74.02041036109651%2C40.76468493796235%2C73123459%2C57174697%2C-74.02144661838506%2C40.763787286314674%2C71437507%2C54107869%2C-74.023181343234%2C40.764524275537%2C71437506%2C56378420%2C-74.02488580841964%2C40.762927206944426%2C70208681%2C53137389%2C-74.02499536680554%2C40.76282736975062%2C61544911%2C52919634%2C-74.025255128766%2C40.763043056957%2C64045086%2C50468096%2C-74.022706%2C40.766034%2C31980986%2C53860545%2C-74.01119897978998%2C40.76307224938859%2C34785909%2C28572409%2C-73.997052%2C40.757120999999984%2C72565265%2C28572411%2C-73.996089%2C40.75678699999999%2C72565266%2C56894152%2C-73.99624562111458%2C40.7557360891028%2C72565299%2C56893945%2C-73.99643110566099%2C40.755446820422115%2C72565300%2C56894168%2C-73.99645881260729%2C40.75513717727398%2C34792111%2C50469875%2C-73.9963936908073%2C40.755113237025%2C34786937%2C28571755%2C-73.995354%2C40.75468799999999%2C34793159%2C28571754%2C-73.995816%2C40.754056999999996%2C34791030%2C28573034%2C-73.99631204662704%2C40.75340322290694%2C34790853%2C28573033%2C-73.99680877546308%2C40.75274331864109%2C63767520%2C28569550%2C-73.9977551018524%2C40.75152360613159%2C63767519%2C53769204%2C-73.99809431314036%2C40.75104408667463%2C34787374%2C28569549%2C-73.9981921201915%2C40.75090439713815%2C34790923%2C28572832%2C-73.99865844251728%2C40.75025253430687%2C75233111%2C28572917%2C-73.99907523313522%2C40.74964206391726%2C34791921%2C28569684%2C-73.999938%2C40.7484%2C34789289%2C28569991%2C-74.000399%2C40.747766999999996%2C62138857%2C28569990%2C-74.00083863991263%2C40.74716233183888%2C34790135%2C28569680%2C-73.99800086277465%2C40.745963420770515%2C34788033%2C28572777%2C-73.99516100000001%2C40.744763%2C34786800%2C28572775%2C-73.995645%2C40.744099%2C34788677%2C28572774%2C-73.996129%2C40.743431%2C34790918%2C28569679%2C-73.99658%2C40.742810999999996%2C34790233%2C28569678%2C-73.997007%2C40.742228%2C34786447%2C28569675%2C-73.997434%2C40.741642%2C34786872%2C28569673%2C-73.997872173852%2C40.741033380692%2C34788730%2C28574644%2C-73.99828699999999%2C40.74047%2C34790914%2C28571556%2C-73.99871300000001%2C40.739881%2C34786868%2C28569671%2C-73.999185%2C40.739242999999995%2C34787420%2C53695324%2C-73.99968655690294%2C40.73855308166271%2C34788729%2C28571555%2C-74.00018299999999%2C40.737865%2C34790911%2C28569670%2C-74.000647%2C40.73723%2C34789952%2C28569669%2C-74.00109499999999%2C40.736564%2C34785789%2C28570052%2C-74.001553%2C40.735797%2C34787564%2C28571838%2C-74.001693%2C40.735534%2C34786972%2C28570048%2C-74.001972%2C40.73507%2C34791072%2C28570047%2C-74.002391%2C40.734339999999996%2C34785785%2C28573075%2C-74.00274464488%2C40.733732427373%2C34788218%2C28571820%2C-74.002809017897%2C40.733615561703%2C74393453%2C28570049%2C-74.00258909325204%2C40.73336343769091%2C74393452%2C57741913%2C-74.00248716930949%2C40.73325368498092%2C34791090%2C28571839%2C-74.00212775330117%2C40.73284109446873%2C34787567%2C28571841%2C-74.001663%2C40.732318%2C34792208%2C28571843%2C-74.00116695741059%2C40.73177398640345%2C34787417%2C28569666%2C-74.001008778809%2C40.731709983956%2C34788107%2C28569664%2C-73.99960399999999%2C40.731043%2C34789082%2C28571546%2C-73.99884200000001%2C40.730669%2C34792898%2C28571030%2C-73.998072%2C40.730288%2C34787389%2C28572873%2C-73.99736%2C40.729941000000004%2C34786361%2C28573567%2C-73.996572%2C40.729552%2C34789083%2C28573568%2C-73.995812%2C40.72918%2C34791576%2C28571086%2C-73.99506099999999%2C40.728809999999996%2C34789137%2C28571089%2C-73.994252%2C40.728412%2C34790730%2C28572652%2C-73.99476486328368%2C40.727804292311454%2C34791648%2C28571183%2C-73.99526999999999%2C40.727211000000004%2C34790735%2C28571182%2C-73.99584399999999%2C40.726526%2C34789507%2C28571181%2C-73.99506%2C40.726137%2C63722987%2C28571186%2C-73.994648%2C40.725930999999996%2C63722986%2C53753358%2C-73.994476277156%2C40.725852627225%2C34790759%2C28574252%2C-73.993758%2C40.725646999999995&options=IGNORE_REALTIME_INFO%3Afalse%2CALLOW_NEAR_BY_TARGET%3Atrue%2CAVOID_TOLL_ROADS%3Afalse%2CALLOW_UNKNOWN_DIRECTIONS%3Atrue%2CPREFER_UNKNOWN_DIRECTIONS%3Afalse%2CALLOW_NEAR_BY_SOURCE%3Atrue%2CAVOID_PRIMARIES%3Afalse%2CAVOID_LONG_TRAILS%3Afalse%2CPREFER_SAME_STREET%3Atrue%2CAVOID_TRAILS%3Atrue%2CALLOW_UTURNS%3Atrue%2CAVOID_DANGER_ZONES%3Afalse%2CUSE_EXTENDED_INSTRUCTIONS%3Atrue
```

however when I put it via the chrome browser I never get 504.

I thought it might be a stress issue. But even when I call only few urls in my code i get 504 for this specific url only.

What can it be? a bug in jersey for long url?

Comment: Did you try so see what response code do you get for another url (like google.com)? If so, do you always get 504 no matter which url are you using, or 504 is only for this particular url?

Comment: Try tracing HTTP call on Chrome and to check if there is something different. What is the correlation between 2 URLs `http://myhost.com/routingRequest?returnJSON=true&timeout=60000&to...` and  `http://104.155.3.206:8080/RoutingManager/routingRequest?returnJSON=true&timeout=60000&to=s%3A34790759+d%3Afalse+...`

Comment: When you run it from the chrome, and run it from your code are they both on the same network ? It's possible theres a gateway between the code and the destination that decides the url is too long, possibly some kind of attack or something else and decides to not let it go further. If they are both going through the same network, then try setting a User-Agent header on the code request so it looks like it came from a browser and see if that helps it through.

Comment: I suspect either a proxy setting or some mismatch of HTTP header/cookies

Comment: Are you using automatic redirection for http -> https in the remote server (apache/nginx) by any chance? That can be automatically resolved in the browser but It wouldn't work in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are expecting a JSON response. I have noticed in some instances, the JSON parsing might have issues especially with embedded Jersey container, such as running it as part of a JUnit test.

When you run the URL directly against the browser, you are not parsing the JSON since you are just displaying the result in JSON by the browser. Browser's are very resilient to handling JSON.

Check and ensure that your code that is responsible for building the JSON object is doing it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

**504 Gateway Timeout** - Indicates that the load balancer closed a connection because a request did not complete within the idle timeout period.

**Cause**: The application takes longer to respond than the configured idle timeout.

Monitor the `HTTPCode_ELB_5XX` and `Latency CloudWatch metrics`. If there is an increase in these metrics, it could be due to the application not responding within the idle timeout period. For details about the requests that are timing out, enable access logs on the load balancer and review the 504 response codes in the logs that are generated by Elastic Load Balancing. If necessary, you can increase your back-end capacity or increase the configured idle timeout so that lengthy operations (such as uploading a large file) can complete.

> **To configure idle time-out settings for an application pool**
>
> **User Interface -> To use the UI**
>
> 1.Open IIS Manager. For information about opening IIS Manager, see Open
>   IIS Manager (IIS 7).
>
> 2.In the Connections pane, expand the server node and click Application
>   Pools.
>
> 3.On the Application Pools page, select the application pool for which
>   you want to specify idle time-out settings, and then click Advanced
>   Settings in the Actions pane.
>
> 4. In the Idle Time-out (minutes) box, type a number of minutes, and then
>      click OK.
>
> **Command Line**
>
> To configure the idle time-out value for an application pool, use the following syntax:
>   `appcmd set config /section:applicationPools /[name=' string '].processModel.idleTimeout: timeSpan`
>
> where string is the name of the application pool that you want to configure. The variable timeSpan is the period of time at which the
>   worker process or processes in the application pool are considered
>   idle. The format for timeSpan is d.hh:mm:ss where d is the optional
>   number of days, and hh:mm:ss is the number of hours, minutes, and
>   seconds at which to shut down the worker process. For example, to set
>   the idle time-out value to 30 minutes for an application pool named
>   Marketing, type the following at the command prompt, and then press
>   ENTER:
>
> `appcmd set config /section:applicationPools /[name=' Marketing '].processModel.idleTimeout:0.00:30:00`
>
> **The procedure in this topic affects the following configuration elements:**
>
> idleTimeout attribute of the `<processModel>` element under `<add>` under `<applicationPools>`
>
> Use the following WMI classes, methods, or properties to perform this procedure:
>
> `ApplicationPool.ProcessModel.IdleTimeout` property

**Reference** [Configure Idle Time-out Settings for an Application Pool](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771956%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)